# Is it possible to change the background color of a website with a gradient

Tags: html, css, colors

I am making a website for a school project and I want to know. Is is possible for the background of a website to change throught all of the colors like a gradient. I saw some options but i need a smooth change between the colors (like a fade).

Answer (score 2):

Apply gradient as [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,blue,violet);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set background gradiant to any element in html for example :

```
body{
     background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(252,252,252,1) 0%, rgba(253,253,253,1) 100%);
}
```

and I suggest you use this site

> best websites for background gradiant is :
>
> https://cssgradient.io/

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have been helpful

**Linear gradient animation**

```js
var y = 0
setInterval(() => {
    setColor(y);
    y++;
}, 50);

function setColor(y) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    x[0].setAttribute('style', 'background:linear-gradient(51deg, hsl(' + y + ',100%,50%) 0%, hsl(' + (y + 50) + ',100%,50%) 100%)')
}
```

**All flat colors**

```js
var y = 0
setInterval(() => {
    setColor(y);
    y++;
}, 1);

function setColor(y) {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var color = 'hsl(' + y + ', 100%, 50%);'
    x[0].setAttribute('style', 'background:' + color + ';')
}
```

```css
body {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Predefined colors:**

```js
setInterval(() => {
    setColor();
}, 1000);

function setColor() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    var colors = ['#6495ED', '#D2691E', '#8B008B', '#8B0000', '#228B22', '#191970'];

    x[0].setAttribute('style', 'background:' + colors[rand] + ';')
}
```

```css
body {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```